# How to use subquery inside DECODE in Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle

I am trying to use a sub-query inside and Oracle Decode statement as shown below

```
RPAD(NVL(DECODE(TRIM(ST.StudentCode),'AB','CA','TM','CH',(Select InternalNumber from Address where State = SA.STATECODE) <=2,'PAS', ST.StudentCode), ' '), 3, ' ')
```

when I am running this part with my original query I am getting error as "Missing right paranthesis" in the same line. What is being wrong here?

Comment: (Select InternalNumber from Address where State = SA.STATECODE) <=2 - it's strange part of your code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add [case expression](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/expressions004.htm) inside your sub query:

```
RPAD(NVL(DECODE(TRIM(ST.StudentCode),'AB','CA','TM','CH',CASE WHEN (Select InternalNumber from Address where State = SA.STATECODE) <=2 THEN 'PAS' ELSE ST.StudentCode END), ' '), 3, ' ')
```

> Oracle Database searches for the first WHEN ... THEN pair for which expr is equal to comparison_expr and returns return_expr. If none of the WHEN ... THEN pairs meet this condition, and an ELSE clause exists, then Oracle returns else_expr. Otherwise, Oracle returns null.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, I tried to add the suggested but getting `Missing Keyword` error..What's missing here?

Comment: @Lara I don't get that error, please provide more details on tables and full SQL

Comment: This statement is used inside a Function. We have a condition which needs to be checked from `Address` table which is <=2, if it satisfies, we need "PAS" else ST.StudentCode. I think default return of "DECODE" syntax is missing here! Could you please suggest?

Answer (score 2):

Just use a single `case` expression:

```
RPAD( (CASE WHEN TRIM(ST.StudentCode) = 'AB' THEN 'CA',
            WHEN TRIM(ST.StudentCode) = 'TM' THEN 'CH',
            WHEN (Select a.InternalNumber from Address a where a.State = SA.STATECODE) <= 2 THEN 'PAS'
            ELSE COALESCE(ST.StudentCode, ' '), 
       ), 3, ' ')
```